# Separate statement to print each operand

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and learning from the C++ Primer book. I would like to know how I would separate statement to print each operand form the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Enter two numbers: " << std::endl;
    int v1 = 0, v2 = 0;
    std::cin >> v1 >> v2;
    std::cout << "The numbers " << v1 << " and " << v2 << " multiplied are equal to " << v1 * v2 << std::endl;
}
```

I think I am meant to simplify the last statement but unsure how. If anyone would be able to help, it would be very helpful for my learning.

Comment: std::cout << "The numbers v1 is  " << v1 << " and v2 is  " << v2 << " multiplied are equal to " << v1 * v2 << std::endl;

Answer (score 1):

Just do `std::cout <<` for each operand.

```
std::cout << "The numbers ";
std::cout << v1;
std::cout << " and ";
std::cout << v2;
std::cout << " multiplied are equal to "
std::cout << v1 * v2;
std::cout << endl;
```